# Water line in garage - options?

Tags: plumbing

I purchased my house in 2020 and there's a water line in the garage, partially insulated cheaply with pipe insulation. It was routed underneath the step into the garage about 4-5 times with sharkbite connectors which I ripped out and am left with what you see here (just 1.) It works fine and doesn't leak. It's also annoying to use because I have to go into the garage each time to turn on the water here. I'd like to know if there's something basic I can do to make this more usable and up to code in NY State.

Typically I'd really only be using this to wash cars in the driveway or pressure wash. I think a spigot outside the garage rather than inside would be better because then I don't have to constantly open the garage door to do anything with the water.

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Comment: *"It was routed underneath the step into the garage about 4-5 times with sharkbite connectors"* doesn't make any sense, but also doesn't matter since you've ripped it out. Garage is heated (above freezing), or is not heated?

Comment: Is the garage heated all winter?  I would have a shutoff valve in heated space so you can drain that line for the winter.  Changing the copper to PEX/plastic will help to prevent bursting.  Quite a few electric code problems also.

Comment: It's not a heated garage, and it can get to freezing temps here in NY where I live. Should I post a second question about the electrical in this corner? I assume you're referring to wires being run without conduit.

Comment: That will be a second question but you know what to do.  Any wire below 8 feet needs protection.

Comment: @crip659 - https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/282527/174289 ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming unheated garage, the obvious simple solution is to remove this line and put in a **frost-free sillcock** from a non-freezing location, such as the basement, if there's a basement somewhere near where you'd like a faucet outside.

You can also install a **frost free yard hydrant** pretty much anywhere, by running pipe below frostline to the base fitting of such a hydrant, which self-drains when shut off, to prevent freezing in the riser pipe.

Alternatively (and you may find this already in place if you look for it) simply shut off (from a non-freezing location the pipe comes from) and drain this line in the winter (and you can run it out through the wall with a simple hose bib, or a sillcock - but in both cases you drain the whole line before winter. It gets messy if you ever forget to drain it.)

Comment: It's an unheated garage. The frost free yard hydrant is an interesting idea, hadn't thought of that. What do you mean when you say below frostline - underground far enough where it won't freeze?

Comment: That is, indeed, exactly what *below frostline* means. In some cases you can modify that depth by insulating on top of the pipe, out wide enough that the combined distance down and in to the pipe location is more than the frostline depth.

Comment: I am thinking the hydrant is probably above my skill level as a DIYer - also given the location of the current pipes (how would I route them appropriately, etc.)...

Comment: Thanks @ecnerwal! Yes - there's a shutoff in the basement that will shut off water and this can be drained. Assuming I did want to run a simple hose bib how could I route the plumbing in the most appropriate way?

Comment: Straight line out that corner.  Would probably try to add some protection from being stepped on at the doorway.  Don't want a miss step giving you a wet foot.